# how to apply validation engine to my form?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-validate, max, min

I am using the jQuery validation engine but need to have a `checkbox` that has a minimum of 4 and max of 8.

I know how do do them separately like this, but not combined. Little help?

```
<class="validate[minCheckbox[4]] 
<class="validate[maxCheckbox[8]]
```

Comment: checkbox... min of 4 and max of 8? What's it like?

Comment: added the code...  sorry it didn't come through originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class name inside your `input` should be:

```
class="validate[minCheckbox[4]maxCheckbox[8]]"
```

^ note the no space or comma after the mincheckbox[]

Comment: thanks for the reply, that's what I would have thought too... setting it up like this does not work.
 class="validate[minCheckbox[2], maxCheckbox[8]] checkbox"

Comment: Are you sure you entered it correctly? Notice especially the two closing `]]` brackets.

Comment: yeah, so originally one of them are set up like this:<input class="validate[minCheckbox[4]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group[group]" id="maxcheck3" value="9"/>

Combining them like you suggested like this:
  <input class="validate[minCheckbox[4],maxCheckbox[8]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="group[group]" id="maxcheck3" value="9"/>

Does not work for some reason... maybe I'm still  messing up somewhere though

Comment: Ah FIGURED IT OUT.  It looks like this, hopefully some dumb developer like myself sees this if they run into a similar issue one day:

validate[minCheckbox[3]maxCheckbox[4]] <--- note the no , or space after the mincheckbox.

Comment: Nice find! Editing the answer to reflect it.